# How much of a boost does Nano Boost provide?

Tags: overwatch

Ana's ultimate, Nano Boost, apparently:

> Increase an ally's damage and speed, while reducing damage taken

How much of a damage boost and speed boost are we talking here, and what is the damage reduction? How long does the boost last?

Does her damage boost stack with boosting abilities such as Mercy's Cadeceus, and does Lucio's Speed Boost stack with Nano Boost? Does reducing damage also factor in armor as well?

Comment: Note to put too fine a point on it, but anything on the Public Test Realm is subject to change before the character's actual release.

Comment: We can't even be 100% certain this will remain her ultimate when she's released. This question is premature.

Comment: @NathanK That doesn't mean the question can't be answered now and be edited later by the person who answered or by the community. She is playable now so anyone who uses her, has her on their team, or has Ana has an opponent, may use this question as valuable information. Overwatch will go through patches so we should expect any answers of Overwatch to be modified according to the latest patch

Comment: @NathanK Did I miss somewhere that this site only deals with content that's out of beta? When content moves from Public Test Server to main, it would be nice to already have a Q&A base about it - not to mention providing information to people who enjoy playing on the test servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ana's Nanoboost provides a:

- **50%** damage boost
- **50%** damage resistance buff

for **8** seconds.   It stacks additively with other damage resistance passives or abilities, such as:

- Bastion's passive "*Ironclad*" which gives **20%** damage reduction while in Sentry/Tank form
- Orisa's ability "*Fortify*" which gives a **50%** damage reduction buff for 4 seconds

However, damage resistance is [capped at **50%**](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753626069), so stacking damage resistance beyond that will not provide additional benefits.

Comment: Actually the damage resistance cap was changed to 50% in a recent patch

Comment: I'm a little confused, if it stacks with Ironclad and Fortify, gives a 50% resistance, but can't go past 50%, how does it "stack"? Doesn't it just overwrite at this point?

Comment: Precedence established that the boosts were additive -- regardless of the cap on damage resistance

Answer (score 7):

According to the [wiki](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ana),

> Damage +50%
>
> Damage Reduction 50%
>
> Duration 8 seconds

Comment: Would like to know why someone downvoted this. Is it wrong?

Comment: @bmarkham it isn't downvoted anymore, seems it may have been a misclick or something.

Comment: Ah probably. I saw a downvote when I first saw the answer.

Comment: Does it also give a speed boost? Could have sworn boosted heroes move faster or is that just me?

Comment: @hammythepig it used to. Not anymore